# AWS RDS Read Replica on a different VPC

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, read-replication

I am trying to create an rds mysql read replica in a different vpc in the same region. This doesn't seem to work. I am getting the below error.

I am able to create a cross region read replica, here obviously the vpcs are different. But it works there and not within the same region.

Any idea why this could be the case?

***The DB instance and EC2 security group are in different VPCs. The DB instance is in vpc-b40d62d3 and the EC2 security group is in vpc-3f6cc45b (Service: AmazonRDS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID: 56d7eb7c-8cd7-490a-b979-ef678f4f6ed7)***

This was asked earlier and the answer was not supported and use a custom solution. Asking again as that was a 3 year old post and cloud moves fast. :)

Cheers.

Comment: How did you try to setup this up? Console, API or CLI? Reading the Docs it looks to be possible. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ReadRepl.html

Comment: I tried it through the console.

Comment: I am having the same issue. How did you solve this ?

Answer (score 1):

Tried this a week ago in RDS console but didn't work. I got the same error. But It is supported. At least in aws-cli version 1.16.

```
aws rds create-db-instance-read-replica \
  --db-instance-identifier [yourmaindb] \
  --source-db-instance-identifier [arn resource url of the source] \
  --db-subnet-group-name [subnet in a different VPC] \
  --vpc-security-group-ids [security group in a different VPC]
```